# How can I find the set of unique categories in a Powerpivot table across a related a table

Tags: excel, powerpivot

Say I have two tables:

```
Item    | quantity
----------------------
apples  | 7
orange  | 2
tomato  | 3
tomato  | 9
zuchini | 2
tomato  | 17
```

and:

```
Item        | Type
--------------------
apples      | fruit
orange      | fruit
tomato      | vege
zuchini     | vege
chair       | furniture
```

With PowerPivot, I'd like to display all the "types" that I have from the first table. In other words, the first table doesn't have a "chair" in it, therefore, the result should be:

```
Types
-----
fruit
vege
```

So I pull in the first two tables to PowerPivot tables, make a connection between the "Item" fields in both. But when I create a PivotTable (backed by the PowerPivot table) with a single column, "Types", I get:

```
Types
-----
fruit
furniture
```

How do I get the "Types" only for the items present in the first table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PowerPivot is by default doing [FULL OUTER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp) when you define the relationship in PowerPivot windows and use it on any PowerPivot Table. That is until you start using other table columns as *Values*.

Try dragging *Quantity* onto *Values* area and you will see that PowerPivot will then filter all the *Types* that have no quantity assigned (it will filter **Furniture** out).

If you for some reason need just a list of values of all **TYPES** and can't use any value-based filter or slicer, you have to add a new calculated column:

[image]

I have named it *Type (if present in T1)*. The formula is simple (and should also be quite snappy if you work with loads (millions) of data rows.

```
=
IF (
    COUNTROWS (
        FILTER ( RELATEDTABLE ( Table1 ), Table1[Quantity] > 0 )
    ) > 0,
    [Type],
    BLANK ()
)
```

What this formula does is *simple row count*, but only for those values that have quantity larger than 0. If that's true, than [Type] column value will be present, if not the value will be empty (*BLANK*) - and therefore won't display in your pivot table.

You might still need to use table filter, but it will now have *(blank)* value listed which will allow you to hide the types with no quantity very easily.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, including about the full outer join, which allowed me to understand how works and helped solve a bunch of other problems as well.